# Illustrator ExtendScript hiding paths

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am trying to write a script (because I can't find one that works) that will export all my separate layers, paths, etc to transparent png files. I have seen many scripts, but all of them do not export all the layers, etc. They seem to just try and export parent layers. So if there are sub layers, these are missed.

Here is my script:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var counter = 0;

hideOrShowItems(doc, false);
// processLayers(doc);
// displayLayer(doc, true);

function hideOrShowItems(root, show) {
    for(var i = 0; i < root.layers.length; i++) {
        var layer = root.layers[i];
        var pathCount = layer.pathItems.length;
        var layerCount = layer.layers.length;

        if (pathCount > 0) {
            hideOrShowPaths(layer, show);
        }

        if (layerCount > 0) {
            hideOrShowItems(layer, show);
        }

        layer.visible = show;
    }
}

function hideOrShowPaths(root, show) {
    for(var i = 0; i < root.pathItems.length; i++) {
        root.pathItems[i].visible = show;
    }
}

// -- Removed for brievety
```

When I run the script, the only thing that gets hidden is the top layer

[image]

All of the rest are untouched. 
I put a counter in and did **counter++** in the for loop of **hideOrShowPaths** and it counts 246, so I know it can see the paths and is actually trying to hide them, but they stay visible.

Has anyone done this before? Can I hide paths, groups, clips and export them all as pngs? or will I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the flag you are looking for is `hidden` not `visible`.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var root = doc.layers[0];
// just for testing purpose. Change the color
var newRGBColor = new RGBColor();
newRGBColor.red = 255;
newRGBColor.green = 255;
newRGBColor.blue = 255;
// make all items hidden
for (var i = 0; i < root.pathItems.length; i++) {
  var item = root.pathItems[i];
  item.hidden = true;
  item.fillColor = newRGBColor; // just for testing
}
// now loop all pathItems
for (var i = 0; i < root.pathItems.length; i++) {
  var item = root.pathItems[i];
  item.hidden = !item.hidden; //make one visible
  // export visible part
  redraw();
  item.hidden = !item.hidden; // hide it again
}
```

In your script you will need to hide every item first, then unhide one, export and hide it again.
I Hope that snippet helps with your problem